# Escaping error in sed called by python subprocess

Tags: python, string, sed, subprocess, escaping

I was trying to call `sed` using `subprocess.check_call` as follows

```
with open(output_file,'w+') as f:
    subprocess.check_call(['sed', r':a;s/^\(\([^"]*,\?\|"[^",]*",\?\)*"[^",]*\),/\1 /;ta s/,$//; s/\.00//g; s/"//g', input_file], stdout = f, shell=True)
```

However, I got the such an error

```
'\"[^\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The command `sed ':a;s/^\(\([^"]*,\?\|"[^",]*",\?\)*"[^",]*\),/\1 /;ta s/,$//; s/\.00//g; s/"//g' input_file > output_file` works by itself in bash, so I suspect this is caused by some escaping problem.

Comment: `shell=True` is **wrong** when you pass in a list of tokens (as opposed to a single string for the shell to parse). You almost certainly want to replace the `sed` script with a Python function, though without an explanation of what it's supposed to accomplish, I won't attempt to ad-lib one. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you are passing in a token containing `;` without quoting it with `shell=True`; but seeing as you are already parsing the command into tokens, you don't need or want `shell=True` here, so the immediate fix is simply to remove that.  See [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) for what it means, why it's wrong here, and why you generally want to avoid it.

However, your `sed` script appears to attempt to turn CSV into space-delimited, with quoted fields preserved, but any quoting removed. There is a Python library for parsing CSV which probably does a better job.

```
import csv

with open(inputfile, 'r') as inp, open(output_file, 'w+') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        for k in row:
            row[k] = row[k].replace('.00', '')
         writer.writerow(row)
```

This is ad hoc and probably requires some tweaking (and I probably overlooked or misunderstood some details in your `sed` script), but should give you an idea for how to get rid of the `subprocess` entirely, and probably have more control over what your script is doing (as well as a chance of understanding it three months from now).

Comment: I abbreviated the question a little bit when posting the question. In fact, the file is located on the remote server and I was trying to call `psexec` to execute sed on the remote server so there will be no need to transfer the input via the network.